# What do "due date" and "do date" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, pun

I want to ask about the meaning of a sentence. What does it mean?

> If it's not the due date, it's not a do date.

Comment: Please say where you found this sentence. It looks like a humorous phrase, a play on words because "due" and "do" are pronounced in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

A "due date" is the date when something is due. The date that something must be finished, or is expected to finish.

> The report is due on the 20th January. = The project's due date is the the 20th of January.

The use of "do date" is a joke.  This is not an idiomatic expression.  It would mean "the date that I do something".  So the joke is "if it isn't due today, then I don't do it today". Or "I only do things on the last day".  But it is a joke, so don't take it too literally.

Comment: The 'joke' probably works better in America, where more people pronounce 'due' and 'do' identically, than in the British English part of the world, where many don't.